# Automatically-read-OTP from SMSes in later versions from api level 26 is not allowed from 2019 Jan 9th?

Tags: android, android-studio

```
    <!-- To use SMS based services -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

we are asking for some permissions in order to use in our app to work with SMS, start by declaring in your AndroidManifest. android latest versions these permissions are no allowed.

Comment: hi wellcome to SO,please explain what is your problem with code and error logs

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/request

i found this is the solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well,

yep because this against user privacy so in order to tackle the problem of receiving otp in android they have provided sms-retriver api. you can use use that without voilating any policy and moreover if you really want to use those permissions then file an application to them. they will give you certification which will be required at the time of app deploymen. but all of this is going to be implemented from jan 2019.

## android privacy policy update

have a look at this reference => https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303

Comment: Thank you.. this one is also a solution.. without submitting form we have another solution ..

https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/request

Thank you @Har Kal ji

Answer (score 1):

if using cordova, use this plugin:

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-android-sms-retriever

github:
https://github.com/diegosiao/cordova-plugin-android-sms-retriever

Answer (score 0):

You can check this demo which demonstrates SMS Retriever API and Consent API to read the sms/otp from device without permission.

https://github.com/sachdevaanshul08/SmsRetrieverApiDemo

Please go through the read me clearly there you can see the compiled report of both the Apis.