# java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10282 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS

Tags: java, android

My app keeps crashing with this error code:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10282 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.
```

This is my code

```
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.text);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        String messageToSend = "this is a text";
        String number = "XXXXXX";

        SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(number, null, messageToSend, null,null);

    }
});
```

}

Comment: Please check your applications manifest. It needs to include the SEND_SMS permission mentioned in the error

Comment: I did that getting this error: java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10282 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.

Comment: you should take a look into official document https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Answer (score 4):

Try adding this code in onCreate method of your 1st activity and feel free to contact me again if any error persists.
This will check for SMS permission and will ask for it in case it hasn't been granted.

```
Here, 'this' is the current activity

if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) + 
    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS))
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

// Permission is not granted
// Should we show an explanation?

if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,"Manifest.permission.READ_SMS") ||
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,"Manifest.permission.READ_SMS")) {

    // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

} else {

    // No explanation needed; request the permission
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{"Manifest.permission.READ_SMS, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS"},
                REQUEST_CODE);

     // REQUEST_CODE is an
     // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
     // result of the request.
  }
}

else {
        // Permission has already been granted
}
```

Comment: is this in the main activity?

Comment: inside or outside onCreate?

Comment: Yes Inside the mainActivity in onCreate. This will check for permission at runtime. If permission is not granted it will ask for permission once your application starts.

Comment: @KartikJoshi and if user denys permission then dialog pops out telling the app need this permission

Comment: @KevinKurien Do you want a dialog to pop when the user needs to denies the permission or are you saying that the dialog pops out automatically as soon as he denies it?

Comment: @KartikJoshi the dialog pops out automatically

Comment: Can you share your code here? @KevinKurien
The dialog might be required by the sms service hence it the dialog seems to be popping out automatically.

Comment: I'm confused where I put this. Do I put it under the Button2 view v thing?

Comment: Just put this code in onCreate method of your MainActivity. @KevinKurien
Make sure you define 'request code' outside onCreate as follows : 
'private static final int RECORD_REQUEST_CODE = 100;'

Comment: Please share your code snippet if any error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>` to your manifest xml file.

The error is generated because the app does not have the proper permissions to send an sms.

Comment: I get this error when I do that:                                                                                                   
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.appidea/com.example.user.appidea.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class uses-permission

Comment: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class uses-permission

Comment: Didn't find class "android.view.uses-permission" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.user.appidea-5Jd70Jl46UIreq6T1EyALw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.user.appidea-5Jd70Jl46UIreq6T1EyALw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.user.appidea-5Jd70Jl46UIreq6T1EyALw==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.user.appidea-5Jd70Jl46UIreq6T1EyALw==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", ETC.

Comment: I think you added the permission to the activity layout xml file, and not the applications manifest xml file. Please locate the file named AndroidManifest.xml, and add the permission into that file. If you are having trouble with it, search for “how to add a permission in android”, it is a straight forward task and has a lot of examples online.

Comment: I did that getting this error:     java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10282 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.

Answer (score 1):

Add below code in your **first or main activity**, if added in fragment it may not work.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                    Log.d("permission", "permission denied to SEND_SMS - requesting it");
                    String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS};
                    requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            }
```

If you have not added below permission in Manifest file please add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must Use SMS intent or you need to send a declaration Form...
**SMS, CALL LOG.. not allowed from 2019 Jan 9th.. Plesse Check this link android SMS Permissions**

[Android SMS PErmissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53455680/automatically-read-otp-from-smses-in-later-versions-from-api-level-26-is-not-all)

Answer (score 0):

After you run your project,you project apk file install in your phone.then you have to give sms allow permission from your real device into installed app.

In your android phone
Go to setting-> apps-> select your project apk -> permission -> allow send sms permission

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34503593)